# Find missing combination of columns from two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, performance

I have one product table like this:

```
productid    categoryid
```

and another category table like this:

```
categoryid   parentid
```

would like to find rows missing from product table

```
select distinct c.parentid, pc.productid, from products_categories pc
join categories c on pc.categoryid = c.categoryid
where  concat(pc.productid,'-',c.parentid) not in (
 select distinct concat(productid,'-',categoryid) from products_categories
)
```

however this is extremely slow. is there a way to do this with joins instead of the not in concat line? the concat is used to account for all possible combos.

Comment: What exactly you wanna do? what missing rows?

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian missing rows from products_categories. i.e. if no productid / parentid (categoryid) combo does not exist there (parentid is from 2nd table)

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you are adding a prefix `productID` & `-` to either `parentID` or `categoryID`.

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.parentid, pc.productid 
FROM products_categories pc
  JOIN categories c on pc.categoryid = c.categoryid
WHERE c.parentid NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT categoryid FROM products_categories
)
```

> **Edit 1:** doesnt account for all combos

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.parentid, pc.productid 
FROM products_categories pc
  INNER JOIN categories c1 ON pc.categoryid = c1.categoryid
  LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON c1.parentid = c2.categoryid
WHERE c2.categoryid IS NULL
```

Comment: thnx not quite the same. original query gave 6500 rows whereas this gives >15k

Comment: no cigar. 8837  vs 2479 rows. thanks anyway. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To find what is in `tbl_x` but not in `tbl_y`, do this

```
SELECT ...
    FROM      tbl_x
    LEFT JOIN tbl_y  USING(...)
    WHERE tbl_y.id IS NULL;
```

The construct `IN ( SELECT ... )` is very poorly optimized.  `LEFT JOIN` is well optimized (assuming suitable index).